# addRange not working on Chrome version 61

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been using the following code to handle copy events for quite a while:

```
range.selectNodeContents(el);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Some of my users are now reporting that the copy event is not working in Chrome. I've noticed that since the release of version 61, this seems to be happening. Is there an alternative to copying element contents to the clipboard in the newer versions of Chrome?

Comment: Give all code. please, maybe  el is not contenteditable

Comment: @СергейПетрашко It has been working up until this version of Chrome though. This is a static application and has not changed in a long time. This event still works in IE and older versions of Chrome, so that is why I believe it's related to this method and not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    el.contentEditable = true; 
    el.focus();
    sel.addRange(range);
```

if this code don't work , try 
use youre code without

```
sel.removeAllRanges();
```

because  removeAllranges will be deprecated, and selection could has only one range

I used code (example)

```
let range = document.createRange();
let sel = window.getSelection();
range.selectNodeContents(document.body);
sel.addRange(range);
```

and it work(tested in chrome 62). 
Maybe el node  do not visible or DOM hasn't this node. Without all code I can't help you.